# Yellow staining on marble countertop by faucet handle

Tags: staining, marble, stain-removal

We have a finished marble countertop that is exhibiting staining as pictured. This seems to be below the surface, as it still feels smooth. Any ideas on what is causing this, it has been growing over the past 4 months or so.

[image: Earlier staining]
[image: Later staining]

Comment: looks like rust .. more orange, than yellow

Comment: Corrosion of the damp faucet metal parts, staining the stone. - And it does look like rust - you can probably see rusty something if you look underneath. Copper compounds tend to stain green. If it's only from surface seepage you might be able to halt it by sealing around the faucet. As far as I know it will be very hard to reverse, once stained.